# Tensorflow facial identification - Shapesare Incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, training-data

i ran into an error while trying to train a tensorflow model. In my code below i can choose a folder with pictures of the person and its name. The Pictures should get trained by the model. At the first dataset it all works finde, but when i am trying to train a second set it gives me the error that the Shapes are incompatible.
I am thankful for every help!

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# User input name and filepath
name = "Tony Stark"
folder_path = "C:/Users/johan/Pictures/tony"

img_size = (160, 160)

# Read labels from the label.txt file
label_dict = {}
if os.path.isfile("label.txt"):
    with open("label.txt", "r") as file:
        label_dict = eval(file.read())

# Add new label if it does not exist
if name not in label_dict:
    new_label = len(label_dict)
    label_dict[name] = new_label
    with open("label.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(label_dict))
else:
    new_label = label_dict[name]

# Load the model if it exists, create a new one if it doesn't
if os.path.exists("tony_face_model.h5"):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("tony_face_model.h5")
    print("Loaded model from disk")
else:
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(label_dict), activation="softmax"),
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    print("Created a new model")

face_images = []
labels = []

for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path)):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        if w == h:
            face_image = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            face_image = cv2.resize(face_image, img_size)
            face_images.append(face_image)
            label = new_label
            labels.append(label)

if len(face_images) > 0:
    face_images = np.array(face_images)
    labels = np.array(labels)

    # convert labels to one-hot encoding
    labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)

    # Split the data into training and validation sets
    split = int(len(face_images) * 0.8)
    train_images = face_images[:split]
    train_labels = labels[:split]
    val_images = face_images[split:]
    val_labels = labels[split:]

    # train the model on the new data
    model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, validation_data=(val_images, val_labels), epochs=30)

    model.save("tony_face_model.h5")
    print("Model saved to disk")
else:
    print("No new faces found")
```

An here the Error-Code:

```
Loaded model from disk
Epoch 1/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\main.py", line 78, in <module>
    model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, validation_data=(val_images, val_labels), epochs=30)
  File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file0ma0lsv9.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2004, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\johan\PycharmProjects\recognitionSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5532, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible


Process finished with exit code 1
```

And here the different shape values:
Set1:

```
train_images
[[[[132 160 174]
   [127 159 172]
   [123 157 170]
   ...
   [ 23  32  38]
   [ 15  23  29]
   [ 17  25  31]]

  [[131 159 174]
   [127 159 172]
   [127 161 174]
   ...
   [ 42  48  60]
   [ 37  43  56]
   [ 21  28  40]]

  [[126 156 173]
   [123 151 168]
   [122 149 166]
   ...
   [ 36  45  55]
   [ 54  62  76]
   [ 41  47  63]]

  ...

  [[143 172 181]
   [144 173 182]
   [145 174 183]
   ...
   [ 36  38  40]
   [ 27  32  31]
   [ 34  41  37]]

  [[150 178 188]
   [145 174 183]
   [134 164 172]
   ...
   [ 31  33  34]
   [ 21  26  24]
   [ 30  37  31]]

  [[142 171 180]
   [134 164 172]
   [140 169 178]
   ...
   [ 46  48  48]
   [ 44  50  45]
   [ 42  51  42]]]


 [[[244 249 248]
   [250 254 253]
   [238 244 243]
   ...
   [237 246 242]
   [235 244 236]
   [241 250 240]]

  [[235 240 239]
   [244 250 249]
   [246 254 253]
   ...
   [235 241 239]
   [238 244 240]
   [239 244 238]]

  [[239 244 243]
   [240 245 244]
   [240 248 247]
   ...
   [231 237 236]
   [237 242 240]
   [240 244 239]]

  ...

  [[248 245 240]
   [248 245 240]
   [243 240 235]
   ...
   [243 246 248]
   [241 243 237]
   [241 241 232]]

  [[248 245 240]
   [248 245 240]
   [243 240 235]
   ...
   [238 241 247]
   [241 244 242]
   [239 241 234]]

  [[247 244 239]
   [246 243 238]
   [243 240 235]
   ...
   [226 229 242]
   [239 243 244]
   [233 237 230]]]


 [[[141 150 110]
   [141 150 110]
   [143 152 112]
   ...
   [ 11  36  53]
   [  5  30  46]
   [  5  30  46]]

  [[141 150 110]
   [141 150 110]
   [143 152 112]
   ...
   [ 11  36  53]
   [  5  30  46]
   [  5  30  46]]

  [[147 155 111]
   [147 155 111]
   [151 159 115]
   ...
   [ 16  39  55]
   [ 10  33  47]
   [ 10  33  47]]

  ...

  [[192 161  52]
   [192 161  52]
   [190 159  50]
   ...
   [124 128 132]
   [128 132 137]
   [128 132 137]]

  [[191 160  51]
   [191 160  51]
   [189 157  49]
   ...
   [122 125 130]
   [127 131 136]
   [127 131 136]]

  [[191 160  51]
   [191 160  51]
   [189 157  49]
   ...
   [122 125 130]
   [127 131 136]
   [127 131 136]]]]
train_labels
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
val_images
[[[[  6  11  16]
   [  6   8  18]
   [  4   5  16]
   ...
   [218 196 161]
   [221 196 162]
   [222 197 163]]

  [[  7  13  22]
   [  5   8  22]
   [  2   5  19]
   ...
   [230 208 176]
   [235 210 178]
   [232 209 177]]

  [[  0   8  16]
   [  2   5  19]
   [  1   4  18]
   ...
   [232 210 178]
   [234 211 179]
   [233 210 178]]

  ...

  [[225 192 148]
   [226 192 149]
   [225 191 148]
   ...
   [204 170 134]
   [204 171 132]
   [203 170 131]]

  [[225 192 148]
   [226 192 149]
   [225 191 148]
   ...
   [204 170 135]
   [204 171 132]
   [202 169 130]]

  [[225 192 148]
   [226 192 149]
   [225 191 148]
   ...
   [205 170 135]
   [203 170 131]
   [202 169 130]]]]
val_labels
[[1.]]
```

Set2:

```
train_images
[[[[213 203 198]
   [198 187 183]
   [208 198 197]
   ...
   [208 183 163]
   [207 183 162]
   [206 182 161]]

  [[216 206 201]
   [206 195 192]
   [198 188 187]
   ...
   [208 183 162]
   [208 183 162]
   [209 182 162]]

  [[221 211 205]
   [210 199 196]
   [177 167 166]
   ...
   [209 183 162]
   [208 183 162]
   [209 181 161]]

  ...

  [[ 33   4   2]
   [ 33   4   2]
   [ 34   5   2]
   ...
   [ 64  37  29]
   [ 63  36  28]
   [ 55  28  20]]

  [[ 35   4   2]
   [ 35   4   2]
   [ 37   4   2]
   ...
   [ 56  29  22]
   [ 59  31  25]
   [ 53  26  19]]

  [[ 35   4   2]
   [ 36   4   2]
   [ 39   4   2]
   ...
   [ 46  19  12]
   [ 54  27  20]
   [ 55  28  21]]]


 [[[126  50   7]
   [127  54   6]
   [129  55   8]
   ...
   [126 136 145]
   [126 132 135]
   [ 89 101 107]]

  [[127  52   6]
   [125  53   6]
   [126  54   6]
   ...
   [122 134 151]
   [132 137 143]
   [ 59  73  85]]

  [[132  58  10]
   [130  55   9]
   [128  56   8]
   ...
   [100 119 140]
   [115 122 136]
   [ 93 105 116]]

  ...

  [[159  70  18]
   [163  73  18]
   [170  80  23]
   ...
   [ 27  22  21]
   [ 30  22  19]
   [ 31  19  18]]

  [[166  77  27]
   [162  74  20]
   [167  80  24]
   ...
   [ 28  20  20]
   [ 27  19  19]
   [ 27  19  15]]

  [[165  78  22]
   [169  82  26]
   [168  80  26]
   ...
   [ 29  21  21]
   [ 29  22  19]
   [ 28  21  18]]]


 [[[180 179 175]
   [ 56  55  51]
   [ 96  95  94]
   ...
   [252 252 247]
   [252 252 246]
   [252 252 246]]

  [[178 177 172]
   [ 60  59  55]
   [ 83  82  80]
   ...
   [251 250 246]
   [251 251 244]
   [251 251 244]]

  [[227 226 221]
   [ 74  73  68]
   [ 66  66  64]
   ...
   [251 250 246]
   [251 250 246]
   [251 250 246]]

  ...

  [[111 122 155]
   [108 120 152]
   [110 121 154]
   ...
   [203 205 205]
   [201 205 207]
   [201 205 207]]

  [[113 126 158]
   [110 123 155]
   [109 121 153]
   ...
   [201 206 205]
   [200 204 205]
   [198 204 205]]

  [[116 128 160]
   [114 126 158]
   [112 124 157]
   ...
   [201 206 205]
   [198 204 205]
   [198 204 205]]]]
train_labels
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
val_images
[[[[249 248 250]
   [249 248 251]
   [249 249 249]
   ...
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]]

  [[249 248 250]
   [249 248 250]
   [251 250 248]
   ...
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]]

  [[249 249 249]
   [250 249 249]
   [251 251 246]
   ...
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]
   [249 249 249]]

  ...

  [[240 231 219]
   [243 233 221]
   [245 235 223]
   ...
   [244 244 230]
   [237 236 221]
   [241 238 223]]

  [[240 231 219]
   [243 233 221]
   [245 235 223]
   ...
   [242 242 229]
   [241 241 226]
   [236 234 221]]

  [[241 233 218]
   [243 234 220]
   [244 235 221]
   ...
   [118 118 110]
   [240 240 231]
   [239 237 226]]]]
val_labels
[[0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Can you also paste the error that you are getting.

Comment: @DevBhuyan Just did! Thanks for reminding :)

Comment: You're welcome, Can you try printing the shapes of `train_images`, `train_labels`, `val_images`, and `val_labels`. Might give some clue about what's wrong.

Comment: @DevBhuyan Added them!

Comment: There will be difference between the image classes from dataset to another dataset. Please verify this or provide us some more details like the input and output dataset  shape  - `train_images.shape,train_labels.shape, val_images.shape, val_labels.shape`